# Naming conventions concerning element sets/coordinate systems/reference frames

Tags: orbital-elements

Suppose I have two ECI Cartesian state vectors: One in the TEME frame of reference and one in the GCRF frame of reference. Suppose I now convert both state vectors to Classical Orbital Elements (COE).

Would it be correct to say that both element sets are within the perifocal coordinate system/frame? If so, how do I differentiate between the two element sets as one was derived from TEME and the other from GCRF? Would you say that the COEs are in the TEME/GCRF reference frame even though they are actually in the perifocal frame?

Answer (score 2):

The perifocal frame is dependent on the orbit geometry, and is of little practical use in my experience. But if you have an application that uses it, I guess that the purpose is exactly to avoid converting back to inertial frame.

You only need to know if the orbital elements were obtained from transforming Cartesian coordinates in A or B frame if you want to convert back into some Cartesian frame.

Also, orbital elements are coordinates themselves, just not Cartesian coordinates, that is, it is not proper to say that they are *"actually in the perifocal frame"*.

TLEs, for instance work with TEME frame, and you need to keep that in mind if you want to use them to compute passage over a ground station, which will require conversion to Terrestrial Frame.

In general, you have to read the applicable documentation in order to know what would be the correspondent inertial frame to any set of elements you are working with.